# How to acess element data when element was radio?

Tags: zoo

1. In Zoo Applications I create element Radio with 3 options: Red, Green, Blue
2. I need acess this "option value" was stored: red or green or blue in database like this:

   "7045c737-906a-4776-b390-0f9529b411a6":  {
           "option":  {
               "0": "red"
           }
       },

How can i load this value "red"? I try this:

```
$zoo= App::getInstance('zoo');
$Zoo_Item_id= $item_id;
$items = $zoo->table->item->get($Zoo_Item_id);
$element_id = 'e455c93e-6514-480b-8891-e61a9ef32a99';
$element_value = $items->getElement($element_id)->getElementData()->get('value');
```

But for "radio" not working;
If i change $element_id for text content this code working fine.

I see documentation for element access:
http://yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/developers/accessing-element-data
But when element was radio, i dont know what do.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I solve how to acces data from elements ZOO. In files:

/media/zoo/applications/YOUR_APP/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/renderer/item/teaser.php

you can add this code:

```
$element1 = $item->getElement('ff944545-de96-45ed-ae24-9126ab82ca7b'); 
foreach ($element1 as $self) {
    $file1 = $self['file'];
}
```

Important:
"ff944545-de96-45ed-ae24-9126ab82ca7b" is your unique element ID;
"['file']" is the filed in data array;

UPDATED in: 2016-10-04:
I found another easy way if your data was in Array:

In teaser.php or full.php you can access any information on element with code like this:

```
<?php  
$status = $item->getElement('0e3527e4-032c-4d35-a630-7b0418eb9ecc')->getElementData()->get('option');  
print_r($status['0'];   
?>
```

In some cases, 'option' need be replced by 'value'.
You need access your data base and see the structure of element like this:

```
"0e3527e4-032c-4d35-a630-7b0418eb9ecc":  {
        "option":  {
            "0": "em-andamento"
        },
        "select": "1"
    },
```

See this other obeject structure ofr 'value' case:

```
"d9f72e0a-50d3-4be7-89f4-4d30b11aa5a1":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "2015-11-18 02:00:00"
        }
    },
```

I hope this helps!